# How to send POST method with quotation marked key data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking, axios, next.js

I found out that Request Payload object's key is without quotation mark like below.
[image]

But I want to send a request with quotation marked key object.
Because bellow way didn't occur a error to me.
[image]

I'm sending data like follow

```
{
   data: JSON.stringify({account: '0x555~~'})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you already did must work properly.Since it's not

Just try sending it like this

```
let account = '0x555....'
data.JSON.stringify({account})
```